# Potential lineshapes of a BEC in a magnetic trap

Tags: atomic-physics, potential-energy, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms

We considere a Bose-Einstein Condensate (BEC) of atoms occupying a magneticaly trapped atomic state $|m_{F}=-1\rangle$. One can then use a radio-frequency field to extract atoms from the BEC by coupling the atoms with a non-trapping atomic state $|m_{F}=0\rangle$, thus subjected to gravity.

Why does the potential for a BEC in a magnetic trap has this particular shape (see picture) ? Same for the outcoupled state $m_{F}=0$ ?

Could you give a detailed explanation of why these have this shape ? For the outcoupled state, I would have thought that there is only a $-mgz$ straight line for the potential, but there is a bump. Why ? Does it have something to do with Thoms-Fermi approximation ?[image]

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you give a detailed explanation of why these have this shape ?
>
> **Does it have something to do with Thoms-Fermi approximation ?**

Yes. Actually what you plotted here is the total *mean field potential* felt by each single atom.

Your picture reprensent a situation where a BEC of atoms in the $|m_F=-1\rangle$ state is trapped with a magnetic field. Then, a radio frequency field (of frequency $\omega_\text{rf}$) is applied in order to outcouple a small fraction of the atoms in the BEC into a $|m_F=0\rangle$, which is not trapped by the magnetic field.

In the $|m_F=-1\rangle$, you have a trapped condensate described by a spatial wave function $\Psi(\textbf{x})$. In the Thomas-Fermi approximation, this wave function $\Psi(\textbf{x})$ is the solution of the equation :
$$
\left(V(\textbf{x})+g_{-1,-1}|\Psi(\textbf{x})|^2\right)
\Psi(\textbf{x})=\mu\,\Psi(\textbf{x}) \tag{1}
$$
where $V(\textbf{x})$ is the external potential felt by the atoms (here, the magnetic trapping potential), $g_{-1,-1}|\Psi(\textbf{x})|^2$ is the *mean-field interaction potential*, and $\mu$ is the chemical potential.

The interaction parameter $g_{-1,-1}$ tells about the *strength* of the interaction between the atoms and depends on the specific atomic internal state : here it describes the interaction between atoms in the $|m_F=-1\rangle$ state.

The solution of the equation (1) is then given in terms of atomic density $n(\textbf{x})=|\Psi(\textbf{x})|^2$ :
$$
n(\textbf{x})= 
\begin{cases}
(\mu-V(\textbf{x}))/g_{-1,-1} &\;\text{if}\;\mu>V(\textbf{x})\\ 
\qquad\qquad 0 &\;\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}\tag{2}
$$
The solution (2) tells you that the atomic density $n(\textbf{x})$ as the opposite shape $-V(\textbf{x})$ that the external potential one $V(\textbf{x})$. In your case $V(\textbf{x})$ is a harmonic trap, so that $n(\textbf{x})$ describes an inverse parabola, as it is usual for trapped BECs.

From the point of view of single atoms, each atom in the condensate "*sees*" a total effective potential $V^{(\text{eff})}_{-1}(\textbf{x})$ which is the sum of the trapping potential and the mean-field interaction potential :
$$V^{(\text{eff})}_{-1}(\textbf{x})=V(\textbf{x})+g_{-1,-1}\,n(\textbf{x}).\tag{3}$$
Combining (2) and (3), one gets :
$$
V^{(\text{eff})}_{-1}(\textbf{x})=\begin{cases}
\mu &\;\text{if}\;\mu>V(\textbf{x})\\ 
V(\textbf{x}) &\;\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}\tag{4}
$$
In other words, in each $\textbf{x}$ where $\mu>V(\textbf{x})$, each single atoms sees an effective *flat* potential (and equal to $\mu$), meaning that the interactions *screen* the variations of the trapping potential $V(\textbf{x})$. This screening effect is completely analogous to the [Thomas-Fermi screening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas%E2%80%93Fermi_screening) of charge densities occurring in electronic systems, hence the name "*Thomas-Fermi approximation*" given to (1).

> To sum up : $V^{(\text{eff})}_{-1}(\textbf{x})$ (noted $V_\Psi$ on your picture) is flat around the center of the trap (where lies the BEC) because atomic interactions screen the trapping potential $V(\textbf{x})$.

The bump in the $|m_F=0\rangle$ potential can be also captured by the equation (3). Indeed, each atom outcoupled from the BEC does not feel the trapping potential anymore and is then subject to the gravity $-m\text{g}z$, as you suggested. But since only a *fraction* of atoms are extracted from the condensate, the remainig atoms in the trapped state $|m_F=-1\rangle$ can interact with the tranfered atoms in the $|m_F=0\rangle$ through a mean field potential $g_{-1,0}\,n(\textbf{x})$ associated to the interaction between atoms in the $|m_F=-1\rangle$ and $|m_F=0\rangle$ state.

The effective potential $V^{(\text{eff})}_{0}(\textbf{x})$  seen by the atoms in the $|m_F=0\rangle$ state (noted $V_\Phi$ on your picture) is thus given by :
$$
V^{(\text{eff})}_{0}(\textbf{x})=-m\text{g}z+g_{-1,0}\,n(\textbf{x}).\tag{5}
$$
Combining equations (5) and (2), one gets :
$$
V^{(\text{eff})}_{0}(\textbf{x})=\begin{cases}
-m\text{g}z+\frac{g_{-1,0}}{g_{-1,-1}}(\mu-V(\textbf{x})) &\;\text{if}\;\mu>V(\textbf{x})\\ 
\qquad\qquad-m\text{g}z &\;\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Your answer is very clear. Thank you for the help, really that's amazing ! It's actually better explained than it was in my class. Since I can't upvote because of reputation I thought I should write you a comment. Bye :)